# How to read Custom data attribute in 'select' using javascript in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to read custom data attribute in select using java script and jQuery in IE8 browser. Both are failing,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option data-date="Feb 10, 1999" value="1">desc1</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 11, 1999" value="2">desc2</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 12, 1999" value="3">desc3</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 13, 1999" value="4">desc4</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 14, 1999" value="5">desc5</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code

```
var date =   document.getElementById('myselect').options[myselect.selectedIndex].getAttribute‌​('data-date');
```

Note : This javascript code works in IE9 and above.